# why this doesn't work and how to correct it?

Tags: php, smarty

in a tpl file, there are code as this:

```
{$LANG.globalyouarehere}: {$breadcrumbnav}
```

now, i want to do if the url is `https://example.com/1.php`.it will add a `welcome` text before the `{$breadcrumbnav}`. if others, it will not add it.

the following is my ways, but it doesn't work and how to correct it?

```
{if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==‘1.php’}welcome {$breadcrumbnav}  {else}{$breadcrumbnav} {/if}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it. put this `{$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}`

Answer (score 1):

try this

`{if $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']==‘/1.php’}welcome {$breadcrumbnav} {else}{$breadcrumbnav} {/if}`

Comment: i am sorry,it shows a blank page. my url is https:.... is the the reason that it can't work?

Comment: is this line is in `1.php` file ?? If not that mean that `1.php` file is parse and nothing is ther thats why page is blank. U can also try to `print_r($_SERVER)` and see what it print

Comment: @zhuanzhou: Blank pages usually indicate a fatal PHP error with error display turned off. Check your server's and/or PHP's error logs to see if there's more information there.

Comment: i put {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']} this in the tpl file, there are no any out put. why?